# ApplicationHost.CreateApplicationHost: System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I'm trying to use `CreateApplicationHost` to render the content of an ASP webpage. The exact code is as follows:

```
public class LocalPageContentAppropriator {
    private RemoteDomain _host;
    protected RemoteDomain Host {
        get {
            if (_host == null) {
                _host = (RemoteDomain)ApplicationHost.CreateApplicationHost(typeof(RemoteDomain), "/", SettingsFactory.Instance.WebFileRoot + "\\");
            }
            return _host;
        }
    }

    public string Resolve(string page, string query) {
        return Host.ProcessRequest(page, query);
    }
}

public class RemoteDomain : MarshalByRefObject {
    public string ProcessRequest(string page, string query) {
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter()) {
            SimpleWorkerRequest work = new SimpleWorkerRequest(page, query, sw);
            HttpRuntime.ProcessRequest(work);
            return sw.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

The path returned for `SettingsFactory.Instance.WebFileRoot` points to the website's physical directory. Have tried putting appending "\bin\", etc but regardless of what I try I still receive the same error, even if I intentionally enter an incorrect path.

Now, here's where it gets interesting. Fusion Logging usually returns something like this when the assembly is loaded correctly (under normal use):

```
Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_wp.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = WICKEDWE-FFB297\ASPNET
LOG: DisplayName = MyWebsite.Web, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Projects/Clients/G/MyWebsite/Development/MasterSite/trunk/MyWebsite.Web.Site/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Projects\Clients\G\Galderma\Emervel\Development\MasterSite\trunk\MyWebsite.Web.Site\bin
LOG: Dynamic Base = C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3610448a\a3b3a5e7
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = Umbraco_Sandbox_98a12b84-6e7b-401f-a543-87e17c021ad5
Calling assembly : MyWebsite.Web.Site, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Projects\Clients\G\Galderma\Emervel\Development\MasterSite\trunk\MyWebsite.Web.Site\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Binding succeeds. Returns assembly from C:\Projects\Clients\G\Galderma\Emervel\Development\MasterSite\trunk\MyWebsite.Web.Site\bin\MyWebsite.Web.dll.
LOG: Assembly is loaded in default load context.
```

**However,** the error shows a different (IMO incorrect) Appbase path:

```
2011-02-08 11:10:03,734 [T1] ERROR MyWebsite.Web.Site.Common.Controls.Forms.Register [L91] - Member registration.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MyWebsite.Web, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'MyWebsite.Web, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
   at System.UnitySerializationHolder.GetRealObject(StreamingContext context)
   at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.CreateInstanceInNewWorkerAppDomain(Type type, String appId, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)
   at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationHost.CreateApplicationHost(Type hostType, String virtualDir, String physicalDir)
   at MyWebsite.Web.LocalPageContentAppropriator.get_Host() in C:\Projects\Clients\G\MyWebsite\Development\MasterSite\trunk\MyWebsite.Web\LocalPageContentAppropriator.cs:line 17
   at MyWebsite.Web.LocalPageContentAppropriator.Resolve(String page, String query) in C:\Projects\Clients\G\MyWebsite\Development\MasterSite\trunk\MyWebsite.Web\LocalPageContentAppropriator.cs:line 24
   at MyWebsite.Model.ProfessionalMemberLogic.Create(IProfessionalMemberInput input, String completedPagePath, String activationEmailPath, String contextPath) in C:\Projects\Clients\G\MyWebsite\Development\MasterSite\trunk\MyWebsite\Model\ProfessionalMemberLogic.cs:line 66
   at MyWebsite.Web.Site.Common.Controls.Forms.Register.btnRegister_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Projects\Clients\G\MyWebsite\Development\MasterSite\trunk\MyWebsite.Web.Site\Common\Controls\Forms\Register.ascx.cs:line 84

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_wp.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = WICKEDWE-FFB297\ASPNET
LOG: DisplayName = MyWebsite.Web, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///c:/windows/microsoft.net/framework/v4.0.30319/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: No application configuration file found.
LOG: Using host configuration file: c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///c:/windows/microsoft.net/framework/v4.0.30319/MyWebsite.Web.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///c:/windows/microsoft.net/framework/v4.0.30319/MyWebsite.Web/MyWebsite.Web.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///c:/windows/microsoft.net/framework/v4.0.30319/MyWebsite.Web.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///c:/windows/microsoft.net/framework/v4.0.30319/MyWebsite.Web/MyWebsite.Web.EXE.
```

Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't now if you get your answer or not, but I'm trying exactly the same thing and had exactly the same problems.

One, and most simple, is to put your assembly inside GAC.

Two, and a little bit tricky, is to copy your assembly to the 'bin' directory inside the directory 'physicalDir' used as parameter to ApplicationHost.CreateApplicationHost method.

It is well explained here: http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/2613.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of `ApplicationHost.CreateApplicationHost` expects to find the assembly of the specified type in one of two places: either in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) or within the bin directory under the specified physical directory. There is no documented way to change this behavior short of reimplementing CreateApplicationHost. So depending on your project configuration and deployment scenario, you may need to install the assembly into one of these locations.

Please take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163879.aspx) for more details.

Idealty, your host will be in different assembly (that you deploy under "bin" of your physical server dir).